# Is it faster to use XML or Serialize() saving data to a DB in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, serialization, customization

I have a project that has a ridiculous amount of customization required.

As such, I am looking for a way that will be the fastest (or near fastest) at runtime and also be rock solid stable to save a variable number of customized fields.

For instance:

The two locations save the same 2 data fields.

At location #1, the two fields must be returned in `number_format($num, 3)` format while at location #2 those same two fields are text fields with no formatting required.

I am trying to find the best (as defined above) way to save/retrieve the format of these fields.

As of right now I am leaning towards saving in XML and `serialize()`, but during run-time, to optimize for speed, I would only be polling the `serialize()` data.  This approach would alleviate my concerns about data corruption in the `serialize()` data as I can manually parse the data in the XML doc if necessary.

*NOTE:* I am just concerned with the formatting/style/etc of how to
manipulate the fields for viewing, NOT the actual storing of the data
in those fields.

I personally would rather not have to save this customization data as raw files on the server, since that is what a database is for and each location's customization data would be rather small (at most 40-50 fields).

Comment: Any estimate as to how many rows you may end up with in the table that will hold this xml?

Comment: @Windle This particular table should max out around 1000 rows, but it will be a very heavily used table.  The table has 20 columns, 8 of which are indexed due to foreign keys in related tables.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but at 1000 rows, you should be fine storing the data as xml or serialized and put into a more proper table structure.  You shouldn't see noticeable performace loses using XML with that few rows.  That said, don't save the serialized data **and** the XML, just asking for trouble later.  Your better off having a solid database design and then formatting data you pull out for display.

Comment: You better take note of @Windle's suggestion, because you are asking for trouble indeed. :)

Comment: @Windle I am not asking about the performance impact of the database, the size difference between the two will be negligible.  I am concerned about the impact parsing of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialized values are not that easy to read (and edit) by humans compared to XML. However tools exist to parse serialized data, like the [Serialized PHP library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized).

On the other hand, serialized values can be easily read back into variables, much easier than with XML. For XML You would need to create a "serializer" that is able to convert variables to XML and back. There is one in PEAR ([XML_Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/)), another [XML Serializer is available in Symfony2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/1467bdb86837e132891dd1b5605248a736cca5fe/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer) as well.

Normally it's wise to not create a database inside a dabase. If you need to, ensure you can easily change that later on w/o changing your application design too much.